# How to connect to remote vmware?

Tags: networking, ssh

Suppose the remote machine IP is **A**,its vmware IP is **B**.

How can I connect to **B** by ssh from outside if the firewall is off and ssh service is on?

Comment: Err, use an SSH client? I'm guessing you've already tried that though, and hit a problem, so tell us a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

From a Linux/Unix box

`ssh user@B`

From a windows box, install and configure [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) or [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/).

Answer (score 0):

This has a lot to do with how your VMware guest networking is setup. If the guest is using bridged networking, then you would connect to the IP address that is on the VMWare guest. If the guest is using NAT networking, then you will need to provide a port forward from the host machine to the guest, and then connect to the host IP and configured port.